# C# replace string " with '

Tags: c#, string

I have this string bellow

```
string b = IIF("L" = "H", 9.0, IIF("L" = "M", 7.5, 6.0))
```

and I want to replace `"H"` with `'H'` and `"L"` with `'L'`.

I tried this and it's not working:

```
b = b.Replace("\"", "'");
```

It give me this error:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: you will need to escape the `'` in the Replace function I believe.

Comment: Could you please paste more lines from your source files? the sentence you wrote should work

Comment: Your string assignment won't even compile. Please use your *real* code.

Comment: IIF in C#? Did I miss something?

Comment: lol, I thought that was the content of the string he is working on, but maybe he is actully using that sentence in c#...

Answer (score 2):

this works

```
            string b = "IIF(\"L\" = \"H\", 9.0, IIF(\"L\" = \"M\", 7.5, 6.0)";
            b = b.Replace("\"", "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Play with this in a .Net Fiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var test = "This is \"a\" string";

        Console.WriteLine(test);

        test = test.Replace('\"', '\'');

        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }
}
```